# Use SIM card on international roaming only for voice calls (sans mobile data)

Tags: iphone, cellular-data, sim

I would like to know whether I can use my iPhone 6 with Pakistani SIM card to make and receive phone calls while roaming in UK. I would not like to consume any mobile data (for Internet/background activity).

I wish to use the SIM card solely for making and receiving phone calls. I would only like to use Internet via free Wi-Fi whenever it is available.

Is it possible to use my SIM card on international roaming on my iPhone 6 this way? I wish to minimize international roaming costs.

Comment: Yes.  See this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/345135/119271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use your SIM card with international roaming without using any data. Just make sure the **Mobile Data** is turned off under Settings app → Mobile Data on your iPhone 6.

[image] [image]

Additionally, under Settings app → Mobile Data → Mobile Data Options, you can choose to turn off Data Roaming. This is a smart settings which will prevent data usage while roaming. (You may have your reservations regarding this setting, but turning off Mobile Data gives complete peace of mind).

As long as the Mobile Data is turned off, you’ll be fine. No app will do any data transfer/use Internet this way (as long as Wi-Fi is also turned off).

Comment: In the above picture under "Mobile data options" do i have to make the "Enable 4G" green inorder to make calls when abroad ? I will turn off the "Data Roaming".  The "Enable 4G" should also be turned off ? The sim should be working. Sorry very new to roaming and data and iphone. I mean does turning on/off of the "enable 4g" has anything to do with making calls when abroad ?

Comment: @WorldWillEnd No. You do not need to turn on "Enable 4G" for making calls. The setting is solely applicable to mobile data. Turning off Mobile Data under Settings → Mobile Data turns off all cellular network based mobile data.

Comment: @WorldWillEnd If you find an answer helpful, you indicate that by clicking on the up arrow shown alongside the answer. If you find that one of the answer to your question "answered/solved" your query, you indicate it by clicking on the checkmark shown alongside the answer (that turns the arrow green). These actions help other users too who have similar query. Please go through the help topic, [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more details.